# Why does core Search fail to index the word "HEERF"?

Tags: search

The word HEERF is contained within the body/content of the node, but when I search for the word is is not found.  Searching on "Federal" or "Cares" returns the page in the result set.

Content contains "FEDERAL HEERF, CARES Act, 2020 Fall Schedule, Health & Safety, Covid-19, Coronavirus, reopening, Sanitation and Cleaning, Campus Dining, social distancing" etc.

Drupal Version: 8.8.6

Comment: There are entries in the table search_index with the value "heerf" but the type is set to "search_exclude_node_search"

Comment: Added a a row to 'search_total' containing 'heerf' and a value of 0.0369476 for count.  It survived an update of the associated page.  If anyone has a explanation I would still be interested.  In a few weeks I will migrate from the Core Search to the Search API.